# Using BME280 with SNMP librarie

Tags: arduino, snmp

I'm trying to use SNMP library to read BME280 sensor on NODEMCU, but I get the following error after compiling sketch:

ERROR:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 3584, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xb0
csum 0xb0
v2843a5ac
~ld
```

MY CODE:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <Arduino_SNMP.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

Adafruit_BME280 bme;
const char* ssid = "Andre";
const char* password = "12345678";
float temperature = bme.readTemperature();
float humidity = bme.readHumidity();
float pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
float altitude = bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);
WiFiUDP udp;

SNMPAgent snmp = SNMPAgent("public");  // Starts an SMMPAgent instance with the community string 'public'


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.println("");
    bme.begin(0x76);

    // Wait for connection
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
    // give snmp a pointer to the UDP object
    snmp.setUDP(&udp);
    snmp.begin();
    
    snmp.addFloatHandler(".1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1", &temperature);
    snmp.addFloatHandler(".1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.2", &humidity, true);
    snmp.addFloatHandler(".1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.3", &pressure);
    snmp.addFloatHandler(".1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.4", &altitude);
    // you can accept SET commands with a pointer to an integer (or string)
    
}

void loop() {
    snmp.loop(); // must be called as often as possible
}
```

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: try setting your temp, pres, etc variables in the setup just before `bme.begin()` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

@ElefantPhace
Another error occurred:

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 3584, room 16
tail 0
chksum 0xb0
csum 0xb0
v2843a5ac
~ld

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Exception (28):
epc1=0x40203c84 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

> > > stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffda0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0190
3fffff30:  40204528 3ffeebe0 3ffe8706 40204825
3fffff40:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeebe0 402048ec
3fffff50:  3fffdad0 3ffeea84 3ffeea2c 40203d68
3fffff60:  3fffdad0 3ffeea84 3ffeebe0 402025c5
3fffff70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe
3fffff80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe
3fffff90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 3ffeec58
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeec18 402050e0
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe84fc 40100c29
<<<stack<<<